# I can't make number 10, 15, 20 and 25 to show on my plot, what is the issue with my loop?

Tags: r

[image: plot]

code:

```
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = c(0, 5), ylim = c(0, 5), asp = 1)
for (r in 0:5){
  segments(x0 = 0, y0 = r, x1 = 5, y1 = r)
}
for (c in 0:5){
  segments(x0 = c, y0 = 0, x1 = c, y1 = 5)
}
for (i in 1:25){
  if (i%%5 == 0){
    text(i - 0.5, (i%/%5-1) + 0.5, labels = as.character(i))
  }else{
    text(i%%5 - 0.5, i%/%5 + 0.5, labels = as.character(i))
  }
}
```

the if statement should be able to help me place the numbers in the right col but not really working

Comment: please include the actual code as text, not images of text

Comment: plase share your data too

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting the `x` coordinate to `i - 0.5` when you hit a multiple of 5.  But you really just always want that `x` coordinate to be 4.5.

```
modulo <- 5
for (i in 1:25){
  if (i %% modulo == 0){
    text(modulo - 0.5, (i%/%5 - 1) + 0.5, labels = as.character(i))
    # or just text(4.5 ...)
  } else {
    text(i%%5 - 0.5, i%/%5 + 0.5, labels = as.character(i))
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach without any loops or divisions:

```
mat <- matrix(1:25, 5, byrow=TRUE)
plot(NA, xlim=c(0, 5), ylim=c(0, 5), axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
segments(rep(0, 5), 0:5, rep(5, 5), 0:5)
segments(0:5, rep(0, 5), 0:5, rep(5, 5))
text(row(mat)-.5, col(mat)-.5 , t(mat))
```

[image: Table]